# Kernel Scheduling for 1024 CPUs

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, bsd

Azul Systems has an appliance that supports thousands of cache coherent CPUs. I would love insight into what changes would need to occur to an operating system in order to schedule thousands of simultaneously running threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking for possible changes to the OS, so I presume there's a significant engineering team behind this effort.

There are also a few pieces of clarififying info that would help define the problem parameters:

How much IPC (inter process communication) do you need?
Do they really have to be threads, or can they be processes?
If they're processes, is it okay if the have to talk to each other through sockets, and not by using shared memory?
What is the memory architecture?  Are you straight SMP with 1024 cores, or is there some other NUMA (Non-Uniform Memory Architecture) or MMP going on here?  What are your page tables like?

Knowing only the very smallest of info about Azul systems, I would guess that you have very little IPC, and that a simple "run one kernel per core" model might actually work out just fine.   If processes need to talk to each other, then they can create sockets and transfer data that way.  Does your hardware support this model?  (You would likely end up needing one IP address per core as well, and at 1024 IP addrs, this might be troublesome, although they could all be NAT'd, and maybe it's not such a big deal).  If course, this model would lead to some inefficiencies, like extra page tables, and a fair bit of RAM overhead, and may even not be supported by your hardware system.

Even if "1 kernel per core" doesn't work, you could likely run 1024/8 kernels, and be just fine, letting each kernel control 8 physical CPUs.

That said, if you wanted to run 1 thread per core in a traditional SMP machine with 1024 cores (and only a few physical CPUs) then I would expect that the old fashioned O(1) scheduler is what you'd want.   It's likely that your CPU[0] will end up nearly 100% in kernel and doing interrupt handling, but that's just fine for this use case, unless you need more than 1 core to handle your workload.

Answer (score 15):

Scheduling thousands of threads is not a big deal, but scheduling them on hundreds of CPUs is.  What you need, first and foremost, is very fine-grained locking, or, better yet, lock-free data structures and algorithms.  You just can't afford to let 200 CPUs waiting while one CPU executes a critical section.

Answer (score 6):

Making Linux scale has been a long and ongoing project. The first multiprocessor capable Linux kernel had a single lock protecting the entire kernel (the Big Kernel Lock, BKL), which was simple, but limited scalability.

Subsequently the locking has been made more fine-grained, i.e. there are many locks (thousands?), each covering only a small portion of data. However, there are limits to how far this can be taken, as fine-grained locking tends to be complicated, and the locking overhead starts to eat up the performance benefit, especially considering that most multi-CPU Linux systems have relatively few CPU's.

Another thing, is that as far as possible the kernel uses per-cpu data structures. This is very important, as it avoids the cache coherency performance issues with shared data, and of course there is no locking overhead. E.g. every CPU runs its own process scheduler, requiring only occasional global synchronization.

Also, some algorithms are chosen with scalability in mind. E.g. some read-mostly data is protected by Read-Copy-Update (RCU) instead of traditional mutexes; this allows readers to proceed during a concurrent update.

As for memory, Linux tries hard to allocate memory from the same NUMA node as where the process is running. This provides better memory bandwidth and latency for the applications.

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of locks. The inode and dnode data structures each contain a separate lock. That's ok. Unlocked or locked-and-not-waited-on locks only consume a few bytes of RAM and no other resources.

Answer (score 5):

My uneducated guess would be that there is a run-queue per processor and a work-stealing algorithm when a processor is idle. I could see this working in an M:N model, where there is a single process per cpu and light-weight processes as the work items. This would then feel similar to a work-stealing threadpool, such as the one in Java-7's fork-join library.

If you really want to know, go pick up Solaris Internals or dig into the Solaris kernel code. I'm still reading Design & Impl of FreeBSD, with Solaris Internals being the next on my list, so all I can do is make wild guesses atm.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the SGI Altix we have at work, (which does ccNUMA) uses special hardware for cache coherency.

There is a huge overhead connected to hold 4mb cache per core coherent. It's unlikely to happen in software only.

in an array of 256 cpus you would need 768mb ram just to hold the cache-invalidation bits.
12mb cache / 128 bytes per cache line * 256² cores.

Comment: Yes, Altix machines have so-called "distributed directory" CC.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the OS is one thing, but using unchanged application code is a waste of hardware. When going over some limit (depending on the hardware), the effort to keep coherency and synchronization in order to execute generic code is simply too much. You can do it, but it will be very expensive.
From the OS side you'll need complex affinity model, i.e. not to jump CPUs just because yours is busy. Scheduling threads based on hardware topology - cooperating threads on CPUs that are "close" to minimize penalties. Simple work stealing is not a good solution, you must consider topology. One solution is hierarchical work stealing - steal work by distance, divide topology to sectors and try to steal from closest first.
Touching a bit the lock issue; you'll still use spin-locks nd such, but using totally different implementations. This is probably the most patented field in CS these days.
But, again, you will need to program specifically for such massive scale. Or you'll simply under-use it. No automatic "parallelizers" will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to bind each process/thread to a few CPUS, and then only those CPUs would have to compete for a lock on that thread. Obviously, there would need to be some way to move threads around to even out the load, but on a NUMA architecture, you have to minimize this as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Even on dual-core intel systems, I'm pretty sure that Linux can already handle "Thousands" of threads with native posix threads.

(Glibc and the kernel both need to be configured to support this, however, but I believe most systems these days have that by default now).